consult-ripgrep - Error running timer: (file-missing "Searching for program" "No such file or directory" "rg")
Emacs 29.3 GNU (Flatpak) - installed by Software Manager
Linux Mint 21.3
Install ripgrep:
apt install ripgrep

In init.el
(use-package rg
  :ensure t
  :ensure-system-package rg)


(use-package consult
  :bind (
     ;; C-c bindings (mode-specific-map)
         ("C-c M-x" . consult-mode-command)
         ("C-c h" . consult-history)
         ("C-c k" . consult-kmacro)
         ("C-c m" . consult-man)
         ("C-c i" . consult-info)
         ([remap Info-search] . consult-info)
         ;; C-x bindings (ctl-x-map)
         ("C-x M-:" . consult-complex-command)     ;; orig. repeat-complex-command
         ;; Filtering: press "b" -> space = [Buffer], "f" -> Space = [File], "m" -> Space = [Bookmarks] and so on.
     ("C-x b" . consult-buffer)                ;; orig. switch-to-buffer
         ("C-x 4 b" . consult-buffer-other-window) ;; orig. switch-to-buffer-other-window
         ("C-x 5 b" . consult-buffer-other-frame)  ;; orig. switch-to-buffer-other-frame
         ("C-x r b" . consult-bookmark)            ;; orig. bookmark-jump
     ("C-x C-r" . consult-recent-file)         ;; Select from recent files with preview.
         ("C-x p b" . consult-project-buffer)      ;; orig. project-switch-to-buffer
         ;; Custom M-# bindings for fast register access
         ("M-#" . consult-register-load)
         ("M-'" . consult-register-store)          ;; orig. abbrev-prefix-mark (unrelated)
         ("C-M-#" . consult-register)
         ;; Other custom bindings
         ("M-y" . consult-yank-pop)                ;; orig. yank-pop
         ;; M-g bindings (goto-map)
         ("M-g e" . consult-compile-error)
         ("M-g f" . consult-flymake)               ;; Alternative: consult-flycheck
         ("M-g g" . consult-goto-line)             ;; orig. goto-line
         ("M-g o" . consult-outline)               ;; Alternative: consult-org-heading
         ("M-g m" . consult-mark)
         ("M-g k" . consult-global-mark)
         ("M-g i" . consult-imenu)
         ("M-g I" . consult-imenu-multi)
         ;; M-s bindings (search-map)
         ("M-s d" . consult-find)
         ("M-s D" . consult-locate)
         ("M-s g" . consult-grep)
         ("M-s G" . consult-git-grep)
         ("M-s r" . consult-ripgrep)
         ("M-s l" . consult-line)
         ("M-s L" . consult-line-multi)
         ("M-s k" . consult-keep-lines)
         ("M-s u" . consult-focus-lines)
         ;; Isearch integration
         ("M-s e" . consult-isearch-history)
         :map isearch-mode-map
         ("M-e" . consult-isearch-history)         ;; orig. isearch-edit-string
         ("M-s e" . consult-isearch-history)       ;; orig. isearch-edit-string
         ("M-s l" . consult-line)                  ;; needed by consult-line to detect isearch
         ("M-s L" . consult-line-multi)            ;; needed by consult-line to detect isearch
         ;; Minibuffer history
         :map minibuffer-local-map
         ("M-s" . consult-history)                 ;; orig. next-matching-history-element
         ("M-r" . consult-history))                ;; orig. previous-matching-history-element

But when I start Emacs I get error:
⛔ Error (use-package): rg/:catch: install not supported in nil

And when I try command consult-ripgrep I get error:
Error running timer: (file-missing "Searching for program" "No such file or directory" "rg")

P.S.
If I use Emacs 27 or Emacs 28 the problem is gone. And Emacs start without any errors.

Is rg installed? If so, does Emacs know where to find it?

@Drew sudo apt install rg  -> E: Unable to locate package rg

@Drew If I use Emacs 27 or Emacs 28 the problem is gone. And Emacs start without any errors.

Put all such info in the question, please.

By any chance, did you install Emacs 29 from Snap?

@Hi-Angel I was installed Emacs 29 from Software Manager

The package name is most likely ripgrep and not rg.

@a_subscriber what does evaluating this code return on 29-th Emacs (mapcar 'file-exists-p ["/bin/rg" "/usr/bin/rg"]) ? (I'll note separately, that installing from Software Manager probably did install it via Snap).

@Hi-Angel In Emacs 29 -> (mapcar 'file-exists-p ["/bin/rg" "/usr/bin/rg"]) -> "eval-last-sexp" return (nil nil)

@a_subscriber well, that means that your Emacs doesn't see the rg binary. "Why" you might ask. Well, that's because I'm 90% sure this Emacs 29 that you installed is a Snap package and not the usual .deb one. Snap provides sandboxing, which means that Emacs binary basically exists in isolation compared to other libs and binaries on your system. Solving that problem more of a Ubuntu-specific question than an Emacs one. I think it might be possible to come up with workarounds (e.g. mounting host dirs elsewhere), but honestly I think it might be easier to just make a Emacs deb pkg yourself.

@a_subscriber you might have a look at a PPA discussed here. I'm not sure what this "pure GTK" warning is about, Idk if it's important… that said, Idk whether you're using Wayland either  If you do then this PPA should work just fine for you.

Actually, you know what, I think I can write instructions on how to build a deb package from Emacs sources. Although I have Archlinux, but I think I could pop up a Podman container with Ubuntu for experimentation. Please tell if you're interested in answer involving compilation from sources.

@Hi-Angel I was installed Emacs 29.3 Flatpak by Software Manager

@a_subscriber yea, well, this doesn't negate my comments as Flatpaks are sandboxes similarly to Snap.
